# APK with automatic installation

Tags: android, apk

Automatic installation of my app APK on user's device

I have an APK of my first app (i'm a student, it's our study project). I need to show it on some event and i don't want to put it on google store yet or at all. I need to provide a QR code to installation. I can store the APK on my server and provide a QR for link to download the APK, but it just downloads it and don't start the installation. How can i make the installation start automatically?

PS. I need the apk file be autorunnable. For example, if I send it by whatsapp, clicking on the file will download it and start the installation. Whatsapp does 2 things - downloads it and opens the downloaded. How can i do it with something, that i can provide to users as a regular link?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install APK automatically when the file download is complete (hosted on private)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439684/how-to-install-apk-automatically-when-the-file-download-is-complete-hosted-on-p)

Comment: I don't see any solution there... i need to make the apk file something like autorunable

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible on normal android OS, if it is possible, there will be enormous threat we should dealing with.seems like virus to me in old windows day.

what can be possible is:
1. create another app, call this app downloader
2. give this app permission to access package manager
3. upload your apk, download with downloaded app 
4. install

another reference:
[Install an apk file from command prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076240/install-an-apk-file-from-command-prompt)

Comment: How can i use command promt? I want people scan the QR and it will start an installation, i haven't any access to their devices...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9355082/how-to-automatically-launch-the-android-installer-after-downloading-the-apk?noredirect=1&lq=1    This one is similar to my question, but 7 years ago, may be there is some new solution

Answer (score 0):

Try Google Drive as a way to store it, then if you have the Google Drive App installed on the device, as it has permissions to install apps, maybe it works.

Comment: thank you, the problem is i can't be sure the user has anything installed on his device... but this may be a partial solution.