# How to send updates of App and auto install with out using playstore?

Tags: android, google-play, apk, google-play-console

I have been working with client and the app is finished and working well on all devices (Kiosks).That APK is not posted on google play store. and it is hosted privately on the website of client.

**Now there is requirement where my client wants to update all devices whenever new version is updated on their websites. So the requirements are as follows**

- Whenever the new updates are made, app needs to automatically get updates just like a google play store.
- App needs to start installation of new Updated version with out user intervention . Here user intervention mean that once he app is installed first time then the app must check updates itself and should install app itself with out asking anything to user.

For this purposes I have read different links over the SO. like, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439684/how-to-install-apk-automatically-when-the-file-download-is-complete-hosted-on-p) , [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17054895/how-to-automatically-start-the-android-apk-install-process-when-user-clicks-a-do) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803999/install-apps-silently-with-granted-install-packages-permission). But none of them is perfectly matching my case.

So the main challenge is to convey the information to the app that new version is available now so that our app starts downloading the new version then there comes the second step and that is to install it automatically with out user intervention.

Please help me in this context . It would be appreciateable.

Comment: you can send push notification for updating new version.or you can create Webservice that check for new version on server

Comment: so when pushnotification is sent then how come I will get apk from the website etc ? and then one more question is here. suppose the apk is downloaded , now how to install it with out user intervention. This is actually a part 2 in my question asked above

Comment: have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/11856143/2941375 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/4969421/2941375

Comment: on the notification received start AynTask for download apk from a server, after completing download start Activity for install,as mention is above answers

Comment: let me check it

Comment: it is not working as I asked and mentioned in my question. by using that code , it ask from downloader and there needs a user intervention

Answer (score 0):

You can let Google Play handle the updates for private apps, even apps that are hosted on your own server. [See the documentation](https://support.google.com/googleplay/work/answer/6145139).

Comment: its for enterprise level

Comment: My client is far away from me , and wants an application which should not be visible to public easily but it should be visible to his device only